# Почему взлетают дельты

Tags: нейронные-сети

пишу нейронную сеть без библиотек. Для обучения использую метод обратного распространения. В качестве функции активации использую LeakyReLU. После второго - третьего примера из обучающих данных, дельты весов, и соответственно веса устремляются к сотням миллионов. Можно ли это как-то устранить?
Алгоритм брал отсюда - https://habr.com/ru/post/312450/

Проект - https://github.com/Xrou/NeuralNet1/tree/master/NeuralNet1

Comment: Наверное у вас алгоритм неправильный,попробуйте код сюда выложить,обучайте с простых данных типа И, Или, Xor.

Comment: На Or/Xor и подобных задачах обучается отлично, но при прогнозировании числа и использовании ReLU (обучающие данные в диапозоне от 0 до 100) градиенты улетают в космос.

Comment: Насколько я знаю данные должны быть между 0 и 1 и есть также разные уровни сложности для задач нейросети.

Comment: Пробовал использовать для обучения сигмоиду и тангенс - точность была плохой при переводе в нужный диапазон. Да и задача довольно простая - предсказать одно число по 4м другим. На искусственных данных тоже не хотела учиться, хотя все они вычислялись по довольно простой формуле

Comment: Попробуйте сигмоиду на Xor если сработает, значит алгоритм правильный и либо подбирать гиперпараметры либо признать что задача сложная.